# Cannot remove ® from the name of an app

Tags: finder, applications

Yesterday, I bought Rayman Origins from the Mac App Store. It appears in the Applications folder stack on my dock as "Rayman<sup><sub>®</sub></sup> Origins"

[image]

That small registered symbol looks pixelated and ugly on my non-retina screen. So I opened my applications folder in Finder in order to rename the application.

If I rename the app to "Rayman Origins1", it appears fine. Likewise, if I rename it to "RaymanOrigins", the name changes as I would expect. However, I cannot seem to rename the app simply "Rayman Origins". Although Finder lets me type in the name, as soon as I hit enter, it snaps back to "Rayman<sup><sub>®</sub></sup> Origins" with a registered symbol.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app name is the same as the CFBundleName, the CFBundleDisplayName is used.

Therefore it would seem the CFBundleName is ‘Rayman Origins’, and when the app has this name, the CFBundleDisplayName is used, which appears to have a ® in it.

To remove the ®, open the package contents (right-click on the app from Finder and choose Show Package Contents), then navigate to Contents/Resources and open InfoPlist.strings with Xcode and change the CFBundleDisplayName to your desired name.

Background: This is meant for localisation but also allows for fancy things like naming the [macOS ‘Wi-Fi’ instead of WiFiAgent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/168605/37797).

Comment: Odd... in this case, info.plist didn't have a CFBundleDisplayName. However, I was able to fix the problem by going the other way around, ie changing CFBundleName to "RaymanOrigins".

Comment: ...which then broke the signature and prevented the app from launching. Oops. So I guess there's no way to give it the name I want. Oh well. :(

Comment: @Wow Right-click on the app and choose Open, then choose Open in the dialog — this will bypass Gatekeeper.

Comment: @grgside Thanks, but Gatekeeper is completely disabled on my machine, there's some other check that's failing.

Comment: @Wow What's the error message you get?

Comment: Going through old questions—if this happened today I would have known exactly what was going on. It doesn't matter if Gatekeeper is enabled or not, you need to completely remove the code signature to modify certain apps. My preferred software for this is usually optool.